Google AdMob iOS is not verified. Even after app-ads.txt update with correct information
I have implemented Google AdMob in Android. But when I want to implement iOS it does not Verify. I have added the app-ads.txt. Also I have checked the app-ads.txt content and it's working.
I want to implement Google AdMob for iOS. It's been a week after I implemented app-ads.txt.
